# Getting GCM SenderId failed (android)

Tags: android, mobile, titanium, google-cloud-messaging

Everything is okey My GCM API key and GCM Sender ID but i get failed

> E/com.appcelerator.aps.CCPushService: Getting GCM SenderId failed. Max
>   retry time reaches. [WARN] : W/com.appcelerator.aps.CCPushService:
>   Device Token is null.

Why?

Please Help me! Are there any other way you suggest? Do you have another way?

Comment: Your warning says it clearly, "Device Token is null".

Comment: Don't understand why such a mistake i get. "Device Token is null".
No problem at all configurations from the panel.

 Are there any other way you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give it a try....and let me know In your GCM class check weather this is present or not if not place it there

```
private void handleRegistration(Context context, String regId) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Utils.registrationId = regId;
    SavePreferences("PUSHNOT",regId);
     Log.e("", "registration id : "+regId);


     //sendDeviceIdFuction(context,UtilsGcm.registrationId);


}
private void SavePreferences(String key, String value) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();  
}
```

Here you save the regid after registration in an app preference try to retrieve that preference value instead of taking the String regId.

OR

Check this out https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

OR

show your code here for more specific answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But I forgot say my has developed an with titanium. I am developing JavaScript applications of titanium.
I want get android Device Token. @Nikhil

`var deviceToken = null;
CloudPush.retrieveDeviceToken({
   success : deviceTokenSuccess,
   error : deviceTokenError
  });
function deviceTokenSuccess(e) {
   this.deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
   alert(" Device Token: " + e.deviceToken);
  }
function deviceTokenError(e) {
      alert(' Failed to register for push notifications! ' + e.error);
  }`

Comment: @KaraEski  check this :- https://github.com/liccowee/Google-Cloud-Messaging--Titanium- and accept my answer as that is the answer for what you have asked

Comment: @KaraEski have you checked the above link

Comment: Yes i'm looking but i saw this link. @Nikhil